# I can't get my exact data out of my csv.file

Tags: python

```
import csv

with open('biomassdata.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    for line in csv_reader:
        print(line[0])
```

I want to get all data from the first row, but when I run my scripts i only get 0.0 in all of them. Does someone know what the problem is?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of `biomassdata.csv`?

Comment: `line` contains the data of a entire row. access the each column using index

Comment: If you only want the content of the first line you replace the for loop with `print(csv_reader[0])`. What you are doing is looping over every row and printing the first field (column).